# Name of sci-fi book set in a distant future

Tags: story-identification, books

Looking for a book where people were in a spaceship to another planet, and when they reached the surface someone on earth had developed a portal and stepped onto the planet at the same time, wearing a crappy suit with a fishbowl for a helmet. The pilot of the spaceship being very angry because their voyage was supposed to be newsworthy, and here this guy and his friend covered the same distance instantly. this was the beginning of the book

Later in the book some guy has a home/ecosystem in an asteroid because he can.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not a lot to go on, but it sounds like a decent match to the beginning of Peter F. Hamilton’s *Pandora’s Star*. Near the beginning, the captain of the first manned mission to Mars lands on Mars and steps out on the surface, and another character interrupts the moment with a cheerful, yet nonchalant, "Hey, how ya doing?"